# How to find the farthest distance from the point to the region?

Tags: regions, syntax, geometry

Consider the following 2D regions:

```
DetectorSlice[xToDetCenter_, yToDetCenter_, dxdet_, dydet_, Rdet_, 
   experiment_] := 
  If[experiment == "Box", 
   Rectangle[{xToDetCenter - dxdet/2, 
     yToDetCenter - dydet/2}, {xToDetCenter + dxdet/2, 
     yToDetCenter + dydet/2}], 
   If[experiment == "Cylinder", 
    Disk[{xToDetCenter, yToDetCenter}, Rdet], 0]];
```

For `Box`, this is a rectangle parametrized by the coordinates of its center `xToDetCenter`, `yToDetCenter` and side lengths `dxdet`, `dydet`. For `Cylinder`, this is a disk. Could you please tell me how to find the largest distance from the point `{0,0}` to the given domain?

It is trivial by hands, but how to ask Mathematica to do this automatically?

My attempt is the following. For `Box`, I just use `MeshCordinates` and choose the maximal `Norm` of the coordinates. For Disk, I use `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@RegionBoundary`, and then do the same. The same question about possible general 2D regions.

Comment: Not sure yet about the `Rectangle` geometry, but wouldn't the furthest point in the `Disk` geometry be the point that lies on the edge of the disk along the vector pointing from the origin to the center of the disk (but on the far side)? This distance would be calculated by `Norm[{xToDetCenter, yToDetCenter}*(1 + Rdet)]`

Comment: @DavidTrimas : for these geometries, it may be simple, but how to treat possibly arbitrary regions?

Comment: You could try "NMaximize". E.g. for a Disk[{1,1},1/2]: `NMaximize[
 If[RegionMember[Disk[{1, 1}, 1/2], {x, y}], Norm[{x, y}], 0], {x, y},
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]`

Comment: Disappointing (adapted from the docs): `Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 1] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\), \(2\)]\), {x, y}];
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 2] = Annulus[];

RegionWithin[Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 1], Subscript[\
\[ScriptCapitalR], 2]]` -- should work for reasonably simple regions. :(

Comment: `farthestPoint[region_, point_ : {0, 0}] := 
 ArgMax[{Norm[{x, y} - point], {x, y} \[Element] 
    RegionBoundary[region]}, {x, y}]`?

Answer (score 2):

**Using `RegionFarthestDistance`:** (newly introduced with v13.3 / using the cloud account)

For a point (`Red`) outside a polygon:

```
pt=RandomReal[{-1,1},2];
poly=RandomPolygon[{"Convex",5}];
rfd=RegionFarthestDistance[poly,pt]
ptonreg=RegionIntersection[Circle[pt,rfd],poly]/.Point[{a_}]:>a
```

For a point (`Blue`) inside the polygon:

```
pt2=First@RandomPoint[poly,1]
rfd2=RegionFarthestDistance[poly,pt2]
ptonreg2=RegionIntersection[Circle[pt2,rfd2],poly]/.Point[{a_}]:>a
```

---

Visualization:

```
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[6],Red
,Point@pt,Darker@Green,Point@ptonreg
,Black,Dashed,Line[{pt,ptonreg}]
,{Opacity[0.2,Blue],poly}
,Dashed,Black
,Circle[pt,rfd]
,Blue,Point@pt2,Brown,Point@ptonreg2
,Dashed,Black,Circle[pt2,rfd2]
,Line[{pt2,ptonreg2}]
}
,Axes->True
]
```

---

[image]

---

TODO: Sometimes, the `RegionIntersection` fails to find the single point of intersection (reason unknown). At times, it results in a degenerate circle with a infinitesimal arc.

The circles are centered at blue and red points.

So far, I haven't been able to extract the `farthest point` from the `RegionFarthestDistance` itself. The name implies that this function is not responsible for providing it (and perhaps there exists another mechanism to get that information). If the farthest distance is available, a reasonable assumption is that there was a point that was used in such a calculation.